# How can i wait for a Tcl/Tk toplevel widget to be created before moving on?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm using Tcl/Tk to build a UI and im running into the problem of trying to interact with a toplevel window before it's actually been created.

I created the toplevel window like this:

```
toplevel .t
```

Then i try and interact with it like this:

```
wm stackorder .t isabove .
```

But `.t` doesn't exist yet and i get an error about the window not being mapped. Effectively it equates to doing this:

```
winfo ismapped [toplevel .t]
```

which returns `0` but if i immediately run the following:

```
winfo ismapped .t
```

Then the return value is `1`.

How can i know when a toplevel window is mapped (and therefore ready to interact with) so that i can proceed with my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, i needed the following:

```
tkwait visibility .t
```

Comment: The other option - rather than waiting for the window to be visible - is to use the <Map> event (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm#M13).

Comment: +1 but that only works on X11 (Windows doesn't have anything like a <VisibilityNotify> event).

Comment: @DonalFellows it seems to work just fine and as expected on Windows.